# iOS application: How to avoid keychain loss upon app transfer?

Tags: ios, cocoa, app-store

My company was recently acquired by a different company and now I should transfer my app to their developer account. I have admin role in both old and new developer accounts.

My application has some keychain-access-group in its entitlements.plist. 
(HQ83N32B50.com.my.application).

What actions should I take, prior to transferring the app, so that future updates performed by the new developer account will also have keychain access?

I have googled a lot and found many ambiguous answers regarding Apple's attitude and will to help. Is it possible to contact them and ask them to add my "old" team's profile to the "new" developer account?

Otherwise, I thought about manually adding both the "old" and the "new" team prefixes to the keychain-access-groups (I noticed it's an array). Will that help?

Any help is highly appreciated!! :-)

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Contacted Apple. They helped me.

Comment: Could you elaborate what they actually did?

Comment: After you transfer the app and try to upload a new version you will get a warning that your keychain group is different. They explained to me that they will be able to manually interfere with the new version's upload process, and leave the old keychain group even though it was signed with the new transferred profile.

Comment: Just to be clear you had no one-time keychain loss because they interfered right?

Comment: Yes @kukudas that's true.

Comment: Just to sum it up. I've also contacted Apple. I talked with several people there. In the end the message was that it is not possible to migrate the keychain to another team.

Answer (score -6):

I found that, when you upgrade from old app, your keychain will not loss. But when you uninstall old app, and install the new one, the keychain will loss.

so what you need to do, is to tell your user not to uninstall your app, just do normal app upgrade.

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: You cannot rely on the user